# Not able to install a python git hub package

Tags: python, github, setup.py

For a class, I need to be able to use this github library: `https://github.com/matsselen/pyolab`. I am struggling to download/install it in a way that actually works. I am using anaconda for this and commands I've tried include:

`conda install pyolab`

`pip install pyolab`

`conda install source_code_file_path`

`pip install -e git+https://github.com/matsselen/pyolab#egg=pyolab`

I've saved the source code into anaconda's 'pkgs' folder and in my root folder.

I really don't know much about creating packages but in my searching, I found that the issue might be that there is no setup.py file included in the code on github. I tried to build my own but I can't get that to work. Here is the code I have for that:

```
from setuptools import setup 

setup(name='pyolab',
version='master',
description='IOLab code'
author='mats selen'
packages=['pyolab']
)
```

Also, I am being required to use the python 2.7 version of the package instead of the newer python 3 version.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to pip-install repository, any python scripts can be used directly from any regular files/dirs on file system.

Just clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/matsselen/pyolab
```

and then use `sys.path` to specify location of library's scripts and import them:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./pyolab/PyOLabCode/')
# all dirs from sys.path are scanned by Python when you do import
# and the first matched dir where the module is found is used
import commMethods   # importing a script ./pyolab/PyOLabCode/commMethods.py
```

Comment: Had a feeling I was overcomplicating things! This helped, thank you!